# Observe change in a property inside property

Tags: ios, swift

I was wandering if it was possible to use `didSet` for a property inside a property.

Let's say I have a function `resize()` that I want to call every time the `text` property of a `UILabel` is set to a new value. I tried using the label's own `didSet`, but it didn't work, as I was expecting. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. This would mean to change the implementation of `UILabel`. Could be that it is possible with swizzling. But even if this is possible I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties modification can be tracked using **KVO**. After your view, which has reference on target label will be initialised, you need to add add observer like this:

```
[self.label addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"text" 
                options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

In your view (same from which you called method above) you should have handler method like this:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
                    change:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)change 
                   context:(void *)context {

    // If you subscribed only for one value, you can resize from here or 
    // add conditions.
}
```

When you will leave view, don't forget to unsubscribe like this:

```
[self.label removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"text" context:nil];
```

**Warning**: `addObserver` and `removeObserver` should be balanced. If you will call `removeObserver` extra time, your application will crash.

Comment: Yep, that worked, thanks! I'm just not sure where I should `removeObserver`. The code is in a subclass of `UIView`, so there aren't any `viewWillDisappear`'s.

Comment: @smeshko if at the end view will disappear from screen at all, you can try to put `removeObserver` into `-dealloc` method (no super call required form it).

Answer (score 1):

> it didn't work, as I was expecting

What do you mean by that? `didSet` works properly for overridden properties. Try this:

```
class MyLabel : UILabel {
    override var text : String? {
        didSet {
            resize()
        }
    }
    private func resize() {
        print("text is now \(text). resizing...")
        frame = CGRectMake(...
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't want to do any subclassing, since I'll be calling the function on a few different controls. @moonlight 's answer is what I was looking for.